# JLDAP for Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

I'm working on an application that requires the use of LDAP for authentication. Every student at my University has a MyID. There is a wiki on one of the University's pages that states:

> To form the full DN (distinguished name) of a MyID, use this format:
>   cn=MyID,ou=users,o=uga (where MyID is replaced by the user's MyID).
>
> In LDAP, a NULL password or username is considered an anonymous bind
>   attempt (bind is the LDAP word for authentication) and will always
>   succeed. Your application should either filter out NULL password
>   strings or validate the successful bind attempt. To validate a bind
>   attempt, have your application attempt to read the attribute
>   ugaAuthCheck. The attribute should have the value of 'y' (the letter y
>   without the quotes).

I am using JLDAP to handle connecting to the LDAP server over SSL. I am able to search the directory once connected, but I'm at a loss as to:

> To validate a bind attempt, have your application attempt to read the
>   attribute ugaAuthCheck.

I bind to the server with this JLDAP method:

```
    lc.bind( ldapVersion, loginDN, password.getBytes("UTF8") );
```

How does one read an attribute off of a bind in JLDAP? I've been digging through the JLDAP source but I'm not really seeing what an attribute is....so perhaps its actually called something different?

Answer (score 0):

There are [JLDAP Samples provided by Novell](http://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/samplecode/jldap_sample/).

You might want to look at the "CompareAttrs.java" or "Search.java" code for some ideas.

-jim